# c# Read line from PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-2.0

I want to be able to read line by line from a pdf, compare it to a string( a filename), and if the string appears in that line, write that line to a list.

So far I had a quick look at ITextSharp and at PDFSharp, but it doesn't seem like these are the right tools for the job as they focus most on altering and printing pdfs.

Does anyone know another way of reading lines from a pdf, or should I keep trying with ITextSharp & PDFSharp?

Comment: Are you reading from text or image in your pdf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [PDFBox](http://www.pdfbox.org/userguide/dot_net.html) with Lucene. It was easy to find out how it works and it does the job.
It's opensource and free.

Comment: here are the PDF Box 1.2.1. binaries for .NET http://www.antoniob.com/pdfbox-121-for-net-binaries.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/).

The library can be used to extract multi-line plain text from all pages of a PDF and then you can search for a filename or anything else in that text.

Please take a look at the sample in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893898/pdf-text-search-c/4896440#4896440) to other [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4893898/249690).

Disclaimer: I work for Bit Miracle.

Answer (score 0):

As you know (I suppose) Pdf is not a text file format. There are many tools you can use to extract text.
Two example:
 - Xpdf.PdftoText (www.foolabs.com/xpdf/) Free - Exe command line
 - Pdflib.Tet (www.pdflib.com) $$$ - library (net, java, com, ...)