# PDF Text search C#

Tags: c#, pdf, c#-3.0, full-text-search

I have requirement to read a pdf file and search for a text.
I should display in which page that text exist and the number of occurances.
I can read the pdf to text but i need to know the page number.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Docotic.Pdf](http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) for this (I work for Bit Miracle).

Here is a sample for how to search text in PDF:

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument("file.pdf");
string textToSearch = "some text";
for (int i = 0; i < doc.Pages.Count; i++)
{
    string pageText = doc.Pages[i].GetText();
    int count = 0;
    int lastStartIndex = pageText.IndexOf(textToSearch, 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    while (lastStartIndex != -1)
    {
        count++;
        lastStartIndex = pageText.IndexOf(textToSearch, lastStartIndex + 1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    if (count != 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Page {0}: '{1}' found {2} times", i, textToSearch, count);
}
```

You may want to remove third argument for `IndexOf` method if you want to perform case-sensitive search.

Comment: As an FYI for future readers, Docotic.Pdf is no longer free. http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/free-pdf-library.aspx
I suggest giving Apache PDFBox a try (it is completely free and has been since its release)

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked itextsharp out?
http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/

EDIT:
To elaborate, in the TOC, i saw a section on:
15.3.3: Extracting text with PdfReaderContentParser and PdfTextExtractor

And under PdfReaderContentParser:
http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/PdfReaderContentParser.html
there is an option to process the pdf content per page.

So it seems to be a round about way, but you can iterate through each page, searching the content for the word that you want and then return the page that you found it under.

Comment: I don't see search option itextsharp documentation.

Comment: @Shoban edited answer to be more informative. i haven't tried it out myself, just a suggestion to get the OP started.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the valuable inputs...