# How do you search for a certain text across pdf files

Tags: search, pdf

What kind of a tools can be used for searching across PDF files. (e.g. Algebra)

We need to search on files in the Windows platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be helpful to specify your operating system and the types of searches that you intend to perform (words, exact phrases, PDF metadata?).  Some built-in search systems like OS X's Spotlight will automatically search for multiple words across all PDF files in your account.

On Linux, I would probably temporarily convert PDF files to ASCII with 'pdftotext' utility and then search through each one with 'grep':

```
find /start/path -name '*.pdf' -print \
-exec pdftotext {} /tmp/tmp.txt \; \
-exec grep -i "search words" /tmp/tmp.txt \;
```

Comment: We need to search on files in the Windows platform

Comment: pdftotext doesn't need any graphical library and works very well on windows too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to extract text from each PDF file and search for a substring in the extracted text.

You may try [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) for text extraction (Disclaimer: I work for Bit Miracle).
Please take a look at a sample for [how to search text in PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893898/pdf-text-search-c/4896440#4896440) using Docotic.Pdf library.

Of course, you may build an index for extracted text and use that index in your application.

There are integrated solutions like [Lucene.Net](http://lucenenet.apache.org/) that may probably be used for your task.