# How to directly search string in PDF using any programming language

Tags: search, pdf

Is it possible to search for a particular string in PDF using any programming language without converting it to a text or doc file. I want to search for a string directly without converting it, I tried to convert it to text and then search for the string but it gave me wrong result.

Thanks!
Kim

Answer (score 1):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) can be used for your task. Please see my [answer for similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893898/pdf-text-search-c/4896440#4896440).

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops Docotic.Pdf library.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create your own PDF "parser":

http://www.quick-pdf.com/pdf-specification.htm

Probably could be minimal if you just need text data and not any of the formatting.

2) Find a library in your language of choice that can "natively" read .pdfs (tons of them out there).

3) use a pre-built tool (like pdf2text or pdfgrep): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/grep-pdf-files

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to search a for a word and replace it, you can go for [Aspose.pdf.Kit](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) contains tools to extract text from a pdf document. Use it to search on documents.

Answer (score 0):

In Java and C#, you can do that with iText, if the pdf file is not locked.

http://itextpdf.com/