# Separating PDF by list of keywords into separate files

Tags: excel, pdf, pdftk

I'm trying to find a method to extract new files of pages from a PDF wherever one of a list of keywords are located, and name the new file after the keyword.

Any advice using PDFTK or other?

Answer (score 0):

This answer should be helpful:
[PDF Text search C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893898/pdf-text-search-c-sharp)

Also searching for 'pdf search text' and 'pdf split' should provide you with a ton of answers.